# Determining indexes based on column names

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

Is there any way of matching column names to the column names which the indexes have.

So for example lets say index1 uses columns name,age,address and index2 uses (in the same table) name,age.(All for one specific table)

If i pass name,age and the table name to a stored proc, what query should i be writing which will return me index2 and not index1.

I have come across many examples of how to list columns with index and table names like:

[How can we check that table have index or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735963/how-can-we-check-that-table-have-index-or-not)

But still had problem writing the sql query for my usage.

Any help would be much appreciated,

Thank you

(This is for Microsoft sql server 2008 - 2012)

This is what i have written , it did not work properly and hence the question

```
select index1.name,sys.tables.name, Stuff((SELECT ',' + sys.columns.name AS [text()]
FROM
(
     select sys.columns.name
     from sys.columns
     inner join sys.index_columns On sys.index_columns.index_column_id=sys.columns.column_id
     inner join sys.indexes on sys.indexes.index_id=sys.index_columns.index_id 
     where sys.indexes.index_id=index1.index_id
) x
For XML PATH (''), type ).value('(./text())[1]','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'') As coLName
from sys.indexes as index1 
inner join sys.tables on sys.tables.object_id=index1.object_id
inner join sys.index_columns On index1.index_id=sys.index_columns.index_id  AND sys.index_columns.object_id = sys.tables.object_id
inner join sys.columns on sys.columns.column_id=sys.index_columns.column_id And sys.columns.object_id=sys.tables.object_id
where sys.tables.name=TABLE_NAME
```

Comment: Which RDBMS are you use?

Comment: What SQL product is this for?  Unlike Keys, in SQL Indexes are almost entirely implementation-specific, so you have to know what type of SQL you are working with to write something like this.

Comment: Sorry , this is for Microsoft sql server 2008-2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this query with [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

```
 DECLARE @searchIndex nvarchar(100) = 'name,age',
         @tableName nvarchar(100) = 'your_tableName'
;WITH cte AS
 (
  SELECT i.name AS index_name, c.name      
  FROM sys.indexes i LEFT JOIN sys.index_columns ic ON i.object_id = ic.object_id AND i.index_id = ic.index_id
                     LEFT JOIN sys.columns c ON ic.object_id = c.object_id AND ic.column_id = c.column_id
  WHERE i.object_id = OBJECT_ID(@tableName) AND ic.is_included_column != 1
  ), cte2 AS
 (
  SELECT c2.index_name, 
    STUFF((SELECT ',' + c.name
           FROM cte c
           WHERE c.index_name = c2.index_name
  FOR XML PATH, TYPE).value('.[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '') [columns]
  FROM cte c2
  GROUP BY c2.index_name 
  )
  SELECT *
  FROM cte2
  WHERE [columns] = @searchIndex
```

In second scenario no matter order specify columns and space

```
DECLARE @searchIndex nvarchar(100) = '  age, name' ,
        @tableName nvarchar (100) = 'your_tableName'       
;WITH ParsSearchIndex AS
 (
  SELECT SUBSTRING(@searchIndex , 0 , CHARINDEX ( ',' , @searchIndex )) AS val ,
         CAST(STUFF (@searchIndex + ',' , 1, CHARINDEX( ',', @searchIndex), '') AS nvarchar (100 )) AS stval        
  UNION ALL
  SELECT LTRIM(SUBSTRING (stval , 0, CHARINDEX( ',', stval))),
         CAST(STUFF (stval , 1, CHARINDEX( ',' , stval ), '' ) AS nvarchar(100 ))        
  FROM ParsSearchIndex
  WHERE stval != ''
  ), max_ParsSearchIndex AS
 (
  SELECT val, COUNT(*) OVER() AS cnt
  FROM ParsSearchIndex
  WHERE val != ''
  ), cte AS
 (
  SELECT i.name AS index_name, c.name , ic .is_included_column,
         MAX(ic .index_column_id) OVER( PARTITION BY i. index_id) AS maxIndex_column_id
  FROM sys.indexes i LEFT JOIN sys. index_columns ic ON i.object_id = ic.object_id AND i.index_id = ic.index_id
                     LEFT JOIN sys. columns c ON ic.object_id = c.object_id AND ic.column_id = c.column_id
  WHERE i.object_id = OBJECT_ID(@tableName )
  ), cte2 AS
 (
  SELECT c2.index_name , COUNT (*) AS cnt, c2. maxIndex_column_id,
    STUFF((SELECT ',' + c .name
           FROM cte c
           WHERE c .index_name = c2 .index_name        
  FOR XML PATH , TYPE ).value( '.[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1 , 1, '') [columns]
  FROM cte c2
  WHERE c2.is_included_column != 1 AND EXISTS (
                         SELECT 1
                         FROM max_ParsSearchIndex p
                         WHERE c2 .name = p .val AND p .cnt = c2.maxIndex_column_id
                         )
  GROUP BY c2 .index_name, c2. maxIndex_column_id
  )
  SELECT index_name, [columns]
  FROM cte2
  WHERE cnt = maxIndex_column_id
```

Comment: Does it matter the order in which i specify the column names for example if i specify age,name this return nothing.

Comment: I think i will have to specify the columns in alphabetical order .

Comment: Sorry your second solution is not working for unordered columns i.e age,name . I tried going through your second query and in the  cte2 it is not bringing all the indexes and the cnt is not equal to maxIndex_column_Id. I would have pasted a screenshot but the site is preventing me from doing so. Let me know if i can provide more information.

Comment: My problem was that I had nonkey columns included in my index and I was only specifying the key columns while querying , i had to  add an extra condition ic.key_ordinal !=0 to make sure the sql only queries the key columns , and it is working fine now. Thanks

Comment: Cheers for that if i had enough reputation points i would have upvoted. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
DECLARE @searchIndex nvarchar(100) = 'age,name',
        @schemeName nvarchar(100) = 'dbo',
        @tableName nvarchar(100) = 'tableName'

SELECT
    name
FROM (SELECT
    indexes.name,
    (SELECT
            c1.name + ','
    FROM sys.schemas s1
    INNER JOIN sys.tables t1
        ON s1.schema_id = t1.schema_id
        AND tables.object_id = t1.object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.columns c1
        ON t1.object_id = c1.object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.indexes i1
        ON t1.object_id = i1.object_id
        AND indexes.index_id = i1.index_id
    INNER JOIN sys.index_columns ic1
        ON t1.object_id = ic1.object_id
        AND i1.index_id = ic1.index_id
        AND c1.column_id = ic1.column_id
    WHERE schemas.schema_id = s1.schema_id
    ORDER BY c1.name
    FOR xml PATH (''))
    AS colName
FROM sys.schemas
INNER JOIN sys.tables
    ON schemas.schema_id = tables.schema_id
    AND tables.name = @tableName
INNER JOIN sys.indexes
    ON tables.object_id = indexes.object_id
WHERE schemas.name = @schemeName) A
WHERE A.colName = @searchIndex + ','
```

Comment: Does it matter the order in which i specify the column names because this returns nothing for age,name

Comment: This query orders the results by ic1.index_column_id.  So ordering is important.  This assumes that age,name and name,age are two different indexes you could be looking for.

Comment: Ya I think i will just specify the column names alphabetically , because the above query returns the column names in alphabetical order . Thank you again.

Comment: If order of the columns is not important, then just change the ORDER BY to c1.name and make sure that the columns are in alphabetical order in @searchIndex.